# image slider for wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

i am working on wordpress theme. in that theme there is a menu there is a menu item "Galleries" in that gallery there are three pages car, bikes and trucks, i have to display images of cars in cars page in a slider and bikes pictures in bikes page and same for trucks but the problem is that when i install a plugin its displays on each page and and every page have same pictures which is not required, now tell me is this possible what i want to do and also is there any single plugin which will display different images on different pages??

here is the link

http://nhra-racing.com/

Comment: You might have better luck over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kashif What plugin are you using?  Also what version of Wordpress?

Comment: i am using "Content Slide Plugin"
Version 1.4.2

Comment: is there any one to help me??

Comment: Can someone with the privlages transfer this to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Sorry that took so long, what theme are you using?

Comment: i am using rokettheme momentum